# Bash Script to Pull Employee Name

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I've recently enrolled in a cybersecurity bootcamp and am having a little trouble figuring out where I'm going wrong writing this script with a grep command. I'm supposed to be pulling employee names from a schedule and the script is supposed to be able to accept 2 arguments representing a specific date and a specific time.
If I type the following line below, it successfully goes into the schedule file with the date of 0310 and pulls the name of the employee that was working at 5am.

```
find -type f -iname *0310* | grep "05:00:00 AM" ./* | awk -F" " '{print $5, $6}'
```

However when I turn it into a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
find -type f -iname *$1* | grep $2 ./* | awk -F" " '{print $3, $4}'
```

And execute like this:

```
./script.sh 0310 "05:00:00 AM"
```

It gives me the following error code of the following and prints the employees who were working at 5am and also 5pm.

> grep: AM: No such file or directory

I also get this error if I have another file with "0310" in the name

> find: paths must precede expression: `random_file_with_0310.txt' find: possible unquoted pattern after predicate` -iname'?

Where am I going wrong with this script? Very new to BASH

Comment: Try quoting your variables? I.e. `grep "$2"` instead of `grep $2` (refer https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)

Comment: With no means of verifying what you're going to see (as I don't know anything about your environment) I see several (potential) problems. In the find you should be escaping the `*` so the shell doesn't glob them.  The output of find will be grepped along with EVERY file in the working directory because of `./*`

Comment: @jared_mamrot Thank you! Quoting the variable helped fix the "No such file or directory error".

Comment: @tink escaping the asterisks got rid of the error. Thank you!

Comment: I would still expect that you get false positives (if those timestamps also occur in files named something other that 0310 because of the `grep <mumble> ./*` ...

Comment: @tink I actually realized that even though specifying to search file 0310, its still pulling the 5am listings from the two other schedule files so its giving me a total of 3 results. I've tried grep m -1 and also tried replacing the ./* with the three specific schedule names but no luck

Comment: Did you see my answer? (Not comment). I think that addresses your problem nicely.

Comment: @tink yeah I did, but I think that's a little more advanced than the bootcamp is looking for at the moment so thats why I have a pretty simple script that I'm trying to work out.

Comment: Check the updated / extended answer ... ;)

Answer (score 3):

I **think** what you actually want is:

```
#!/bin/bash 
find -type f -iname "*${1}*" -exec awk  -v i="${2}" '$0 ~ i {print $5, $6}' "{}" +
```

Note that `awk` by default uses any number of whitespace (spaces, tabs) as a separator, so your field-separator may not actually be what you need/want, either.

And a different approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep "${2}" $( find -type f -iname "*${1}*" ) | awk '{print $5, $6}'
```

Slightly shorter (less typing), but more processes involved.

Comment: Would there have been a way to limit it to one result the way I had it with the find and then the grep or no? Was curious why the m - 1 didn't work when I tried.

Comment: No. Your grep would act on the filename that find outputs (not getting a match) and then on all the files in the current directory. You can't feed grep a filename on STDIN.

Comment: I don't think `grep` looks at the pipe at all if it gets filename arguments, does it?

Comment: Oops. No, you're right @PaulHodges . That's an `xor` for the input.

Answer (score 1):

You first problem is quoting.

> grep: AM: No such file or directory

This is because what `grep $2 ./*` is running is

```
grep 05:00:00 AM
```

making `AM` the file argument, followed by the expansion of `./*` which is every file in whatever directory you ran the command from, which is also not what you want. You quoted it correctly in your CLI example, but you have to quote it in your script.

```
grep "$2" ./* # still not looking at the right file
```

This will pass the "5:00:00 AM" correctly, but isn't going to search for it in the file(s) returned from `find`.

*Assuming* there is only one file (I wouldn't, but for simplicity's sake...) - try

```
file=`find -type f -iname *"$1"*` # note the quoting here also
```

Personally, I prefer the improved syntax for the same thing -

```
file="$(find -type f -iname *"$1"*)" # note the quoting here also
```

If there is *any* chance you are going to get multiple files, then this is likely way beyond the scope of a bootcamp unless they are really doing it right, in which case c.f. [this discussion of why filenames are not to be trusted](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

ANYWAY - once you have your filename, you still don't need `grep`.

```
awk -v ts="$ts" '$0~ts{print $5, $6}' "$file"
```

or even, in one step,

```
awk -v ts="$ts" '$0~ts{print $5, $6}' "$(find -type f -iname *"$1"*)"
```

...but if you just felt the need to add a redundant pattern parser antipattern, then

```
grep "$2" "$(find -type f -iname *"$1"*)" | awk '{print $5, $6}'
```

A possible alternative, with no promises on performance...

```
#/bin/bash
ts="$1";                # save the string search pattern
shift;                  # and shift it off the argument list
shopt -s globstar;      # make ** match an arbitrary depth of folders
awk -v ts="$ts" '$0~ts{print $5, $6}' "$@" # just use awk
```

Call it with

```
./script.sh "05:00:00 AM" **/*0310* # pass search pattern first, then file list
```

This should let the interpreter locate matching files for you and pass that list to the script. `awk` itself will only open the files it is passed as arguments, so you no longer need the `find`. `awk` can also pattern match for lines in those files, so you no longer need the separate `grep`.

(This does run the possibility of returning directories and other weirdness as well as just plain files; we can add lines to accommodate that, but I'm trying to keep it fairly simple for the given problem.)

I omitted the `-F" "` - you probably don't need that, but be sure to test to see if it changes your actual output dataset. If what you literally meant was that you want *every* space to delimit a field, so that consecutive spaces mean empty fields, use `-F'[ ]'`.

If that's too fancy for your context, tink's answer is probably what you want.